# How can I find the time complexity of this algorithm (backtracking)?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

This is a function I wrote in Python for Leetcode 216. The problem statement is:

> Find all combinations of k distinct digits from [1-9] s.t they sum to n. Return a list of all valid combinations, knowing that 2 <= k <= 9, 1 <= n <= 60

This is my algorithm:

```
def combinationSum(k: int, n: int) -> list[list[int]]:

        def backtrack(res, start, cur, curSum):
            print(res, start, cur, curSum)
            if len(cur) == k:
                if curSum == n:
                    res.append(cur[:])
                return

            for i in range(start, 10):
                cur.append(i)
                backtrack(res, i + 1, cur, curSum + i)
                cur.pop()
        
        c = []
        backtrack(c, 1, [], 0)
        return c
```

and it is correct. I am having trouble with the time complexity though. I understand it is exponential, but how can I go about deducing it?

Comment: Step one, write a recurrence relation. What is the cost of a call to `backtrack`, allowing for recursion in the mathematical definition.

Comment: It's O(1) because no matter how large n is you iterate over at most 2^9 things.

Comment: I do not know it mathematically @JohnKugelman. What course would I learn that in?

Comment: @PaulHankin I think a more precise bound would be 9Ck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually:

[image]

Why?:

- Each time you pick *`upto`* `k` distinct digits out of `9` available ones. (I think it is already clear to you as per your comment)
- The base case always starts with `[i]` (single sized `cur`) up to `[i, i+1,...]` (`k` sized `cur`)

  - Therefore, all the `k` th iterations of `backtrack` includes `1 to (k-1)th` generations (`9C1 + 9C2 + ... + 9Ck`)